# Making sense of weak topology and set of continuous maps

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces, banach-spaces, weak-topology

It is common knowledge, for Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$, the space of bounded linear operators $\mathcal{B}(X,Y)$ is exactly the space of continuous linear maps. The weak topology on $X$ is then defined as the coarsest topology such that every norm-continuous linear functional in $X^*:=\mathcal{B}(X, \mathbb{F})$ remains continuous, where $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R};\mathbb{C}$ is the underlying (complete) field.

But, in general, if $X$ and $Y$ are general topological spaces, we cannot expect modifying the topology on $X$ won't result in changes of the set of continuous functions to $Y$. A smaller topology would generally result in less continuous functions.

So my questions are,

1. under what circumstances in general, can we have the phenomenon where changing the topology of $X$ doesn't change the set of continuous functions?
2. In the context of infinitely dimensional Banach spaces, do there exist weak continuous **nolinear** functionals? That is, under the weak topology, do we have $C(X, \mathbb{F})=X^*$, when Banach space $X$ has infinite dimensions?

Update:

> After some thoughts, it seems I omitted something. The set of norm-continuous functions $C(X, Y)$ is **much larger** than the set of norm-continuous *linear* functions $\mathcal{B}(X,Y)$. When we modify the topology on $X$, in general, the size of $C(X, Y)$ cannot remain the same. But weak topology is about preserving the continuity of the *linear* functionals in the continuous dual $X^*$.

Comment: finite dimensional spaces.

Comment: Your question is not that clear, even after the update. Can you state it more precisely? Some remarks: you wrote that the weak topology in B. spaces is the one that makes $B(X,\mathbb F)$ and $C(X,\mathbb F)$ coincide (where in the latter you assume $X$ has the weak topology), but this is not true (think about a finite dimensional space, where weak and strong topologies coincide). Second: note that even in the linear setting, the elements of $X^*$ are still continuous from $X$ (weak) to $\mathbb F$, but not all elements of $B(X,Y)$ for arbitrary B. space $Y$ (unless $Y$ has finite dimension).

Comment: The question is not clear because (in the question) it seems you are talking about a general topological space $X$ and asking whether $C(X,Y)$ can remain the same when changing the topology of $X$. But then it is not clear how the question is linked to the B. space setting, where the weak topology changes the set $C(X,Y)$ in general. In the update you say“We are not asking all continuous functions to not get affected. Only the linear ones”. So, is your question about general topological spaces $X,Y$ and the space $C(X,Y)$, or do you want to consider a special subset of $C(X,Y)$  (e.g. linear)?

Comment: @LorenzoPompili updated

Comment: Of course, there exist weakly continuous non-linear maps, e.g., constant maps or, less trivially, $x\mapsto f(x)^2$ for a continuous non-zero linear functional $f\in X^*$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your first question is very broad and can have many interesting answers depending on the context. The point is that, since you are considering $C(X,Y)$, the answer depends a lot on what is the topology of the other space $Y$.
If you allow the topology of $Y$ to vary too, you can essentially make the set $C(X,Y)$ to be either the set of constant functions or the set of all functions. But if the topology of $Y$ is fixed (and somewhat nontrivial) you could have interesting behaviours, see the answer by Jochen.

Concerning the second question, as (again) Jochen suggests in a few comments, you can construct many examples, e.g. by composing any linear functional $f\in X^*$ with any continuous function $\phi:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$.

In the above example, though, you are basically reducing yourself to the finite-dimensional case, where weak and strong topologies coincide. In fact, you can view any non-trivial functional $\phi\in X^*$ as a linear projection onto a one-dimensional space. I think that constructing a "genuinely infinite-dimensional" example is a bit less trivial (if not impossible, I don't know).

Even though this is not completely related, I want to mention the case of convex functions: if you have a continuous convex functional $\phi:X\to\mathbb R$, this is authomatically lower-semicontinuous in the weak topology of $X$ (this is related to the fact that a strongly closed, convex subset of a Banach space $X$ is also weakly closed), but you cannot upgrade this statement to continuous functions. In fact (again, again), Jochen suggests the example of the norm $||\cdot\||$, which is convex and continuous, thus weakly lower-semicontinuous, but not weakly continuous (there exist sequences of unitary vectors that converge weakly to zero). If you want to look at some references, have a look at the book of H. Brezis "Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations".

Answer (score 1):

Pavel Urysohn constructed a Hausdorff topological space $(X,\tau)$ such that every continuous $f:X\to\mathbb R$ is constant, so that $\tau$ and the trivial topology $\{\emptyset,X\}$ have the same continuous real-valued functions. Such strange things do not happen in *completely regular* spaces where a set $A$ is closed if and only if, for every $x\notin A$, there is a continuous real-valued function vanishing on $A$ with $f(x)=1$. Thus, two completely regular topologies on a set coincide if they have the same continuous real-valued functions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I updated the question, to make it more clear. Is there any chance you can comment on the 2nd part of the question?

Comment: If $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ is an infinite dimensional normed space, then  $\|\cdot\|:X\to\mathbb R$ is norm-continuous (which follows from the *lower* triangle inequality $|\|x\|-\|y\||\le \|x-y\|$) but it is not continuous at $0$ as a map $(X,\sigma(X,X^*))\to\mathbb R$ because every weak $0$-neighbourhood contains subspaces.